# Step by step guide for SSO implementation using Shiro

Tags: single-sign-on, cas, shiro

I am new to Apache Shiro. I know the basic concepts of SSO.
I need to create a POC (at my localhost using Tomcat) for SSO something similar to mentioned at http://shiro.apache.org/cas.html

I am not sure how and where to start.

When I downloaded source code "shiro-root-1.2.3" I saw there are many sample projects and cas is also there.

Kindly help me and let me know if there are any step by step instructions for implementing SSO?

I could run web and spring projects using "mvn clean jetty:run" command and "samples/quickstart" project using "mvn compile exec:java" command.

I could not find the way to run "cas" project.

Please let me know how to run existing cas project and use that in web/spring projects?

Regards,
Krishan Babbar

Comment: clone this and give it a shot https://github.com/leleuj/java-shiro-cas-client-demo

Answer (score 1):

The people at [Stormpath](https://www.stormpath.com) have written a very detailed explanation on how to achieve SSO with Shiro for their product. I am sure the steps will be almost identical in your case.

Here it is: https://support.stormpath.com/hc/en-us/articles/203815036-Can-I-SSO-between-multiple-Wars-in-the-same-servlet-with-Stormpath-and-Apache-Shiro-

Comment: Thanks jstack, I need to do it on 2 different tomcats. Please see my another thread at http://shiro-user.582556.n2.nabble.com/Step-by-step-guide-for-SSO-implementation-using-Shiro-td7580556.html#a7580558 My next question is, I need to allow OAuth, Facebook login, Google+ Login and Form based login in my CAS server. Do "https://github.com/leleuj/cas-overlay-demo" will work? Is it allow to use on production? Or do i need to write everything by myself?

Comment: The link posted in the solution is invlid

Comment: Stormpath does not exist anymore. I could send you the article as I wrote it myself. I need to search it though. I will share it with you as soon as I find it.